# Passing integer value from html data-enum element

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<html>
        <p data-enum=NewEnum.EnumTypeA> </p>

        var NewEnum= {
                EnumTypeA: 1
        }
</html>


I am extracting this enum in another js file:
JAVASCRIPT CODE:
$(p).click(function()
{
    var e = $(this).data('enum');
}
```

I get 'e' as string EnumTypeA and not 1. How should i pass it to get it as integer?

Comment: Please give more details. Provide HTML code and javascript code in detail.

Comment: I think i mistakenly removed the HTML code:

<p data-enum=NewEnum.EnumTypeA> </p>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the `data-enum` attribute value is a "string", not an object or an object variabel or an integer or ...

Doing this migth help you:

```
<p data-enum=EnumTypeA> </p>
```

```
var NewEnum= { EnumTypeA: 1 }
```

```
var e = $(this).data('enum');
var eint = parseInt(NewEnum[e]);
```

**Edit**

Here is a snippet that shows how it works:

```js
var NewEnum= { EnumTypeA: 1 }

function getInt(p) {
  
  var e = p.getAttribute('data-enum');
  var eint = parseInt(NewEnum[e]);
  
  var chkvalue = document.getElementById("chkvalue");
  chkvalue.innerHTML = "The enum values is: " + eint;
  
}
```

```html
<p onclick="getInt(this);" data-enum=EnumTypeA> Click here </p>
<p id="chkvalue"> </p>
```

Comment: Not working..
Its doing like parseInt(NewEnum["NewEnum.EnumTypeA"])
This gives me NaN

Comment: @sahil Updated my answer with a sample

Comment: perfect. working!! I had to pass only EnumTypeA.
parseInt(NewEnum["NewEnum.EnumTypeA"]) would return NaN
parseInt(NewEnum["EnumTypeA"]) would return THE RESULT.